# standard format to convert string to datetime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

string value ="15:10"
I have to convert string value "15:10" to like this "1899-12-30 15:10:00.000" 
i write below code is there any standard date/time format.

```
 Private Function GetCurrentTime(ByVal dtnew As String) As DateTime

        Dim oaDate As DateTime
        Dim timeValue As DateTime
        Dim dtNow As DateTime
        'Final date time to be stored in the time field

        oaDate = DateTime.FromOADate(0)
        dtnew = String.Concat(oaDate.Year, oaDate.Month, oaDate.Day, dtnew)
        dtnew = dtnew.Replace(":", String.Empty)
        dtNow = DateTime.ParseExact(dtnew, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 'Convert.ToDateTime(dtnew).ToString("HH:mm")
        timeValue = dtNow 'New DateTime(oaDate.Year, oaDate.Month, oaDate.Day, dtNow.Hour, dtNow.Minute, dtNow.Second)
        Return timeValue

    End Function
```

Comment: I don't get what you need

Comment: i have updated quetion

Comment: You have the other values like year etc?

Comment: string value ="15:10" ,  I have to convert string value "15:10" to "1899-12-30 15:10:00.000"  for that i have used mentioned code in question is there  any other way to do same

Comment: If this question is asking for the datetime format, then it really isn't very clear. However, it depends on the location, as different countries have different formats, however I use `ddMMyyyy hhmmss tt`

Comment: i need standard format that is independent of machine foramt

Comment: If you've already achieved the task, why ask for a different way, unless this way is causing errors or there's a reason you can't use it?

Comment: i need to optimize the code

Comment: Why do you need to optimise the code? What's the problem? Is it using too much memory, taking too long (define "too long")?.

Comment: If you replace your format string with "yyyyMMddHH:mm" (i.e. add a colon) you won't need the line `dtnew = dtnew.Realace(":", string.Empty)`

Comment: i have hardcoded dateformat thats the casue ineed some standard date format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a DateTime object you just need to control how it's output when you call it's `.ToString()` method.

There's a [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes a format string. If you want the output to be:

> 1899-12-30 15:10:00.000

then the string you need to provide is:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

Also, when you are parsing the date you can include the colon in the parsing format string ("yyyyMMddHH:mm") so you won't need the line

```
dtnew = dtnew.Replace(":", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the string passed is always of format "HH:mm", you just have to replace these elements into the DateTime you will return.

```
Private Function GetCurrentTime(ByVal dtnew As String) As DateTime
    'We get the date
    Dim oaDate As DateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(0)
    'We change the Hour
    oaDate.Hour = dtNew.Substring(0, 2)
    'We change the minutes
    oaDate.Minute = dtNew.Substring(3, 2)
    return oaDate
End Function
```

The output format of this date does not matter, because you modify the fields of the DateTime structure.